# Good Add-on to show coordinates in World of Warcraft

Tags: world-of-warcraft, mods

What is a simple Add-on that shows coordinates in WoW?

I found information about Koordinator and Cartographer in the Web, but both does not work (they are outdated, at least the versions I found) giving many Lua script errors when I enable them.

I've tried Carbonite as well, but it is very confusing and heavy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [TomTom](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/fileinfo.php?id=7032) for as long as I can remember.

Out of the box it not only includes a really simple coordinate box, but a way to have an arrow point to any arbitrary set of coordinates:

[image: Coordinate box]
[image: Waypoint arrow]

Answer (score 0):

I use [Mapster](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/mapster.aspx), which makes you map awesome in general and also adds a coordinate display to the map screen.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to display coordinates outside the map window, but I haven't really tried. I find I usually don't care where I am, just where the right point on the map is, but your mileage may vary.